# boost::bind internal copy/copies?

Tags: c++, boost, bind, internals

I was hoping to understand what kind of internal copies of a function object does boost::bind do. Since constructors of these objects do not seem to be invoked, I presumed this is a kind of "very shallow copy", so I introduced dynamic memory allocations to produce some errors. However, runtime output of the code below seems to indicate *three* additional destructor calls for internal copies made by bind.

```
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

class M{
    int *somedata;
public:
    M(){ somedata=new int[5]; cout<<"from cstr\n"; somedata[1]=0;}
    ~M(){cout<<"from dstr\n"; delete somedata;}

    int operator()(int i){ cout<<++somedata[i]<<endl; return 0;}
};


int main()
{
    M instM;

    bind<int>(instM,1)();
    //bind<int>(&M::operator(),&instM,1)(); //this works with no errors, of course

    instM(1); //would not change the order of output

    return 0;
}
```

The output ... presents some additional puzzles - eg. why first dstr event comes before call to operator()? Also notice the "2" before the last failed destructor call.

```
from cstr
from dstr
1
from dstr
bind_copy(73365) malloc: *** error for object 0x1001b0: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
from dstr
bind_copy(73365) malloc: *** error for object 0x1001b0: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
2
from dstr
bind_copy(73365) malloc: *** error for object 0x1001b0: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

So the question is: can anyone explain briefly in what order, and what kind of copies does bind make?

... After some thought I realized bind is simply using the (here default) copy constructor. After supplying some custom version of this cstr (with memory allocation and as-deep-as-one-wishes version of the copy) the output gets clean (as it should), but the puzzle remains: there are *three* invocations of the copy constructor. **So in this case boost::bind makes *three* copies of the function object. Why and in which order?** (For nested boost::binds this can lead to quite explosive growth of the number of internal copies.)

Output with cp-cstr defined, and some "heritage markers" added ("P"=parent, each cp cstr adds "-C"):

```
 from cstr P
 from cp cstr P-C
 from cp cstr P-C-C
 from cp cstr P-C-C-C
 from dstr P-C-C
 P-C-C-C:1
 from dstr P-C-C-C
 from dstr P-C
 P:1
 from dstr P
```

Comment: Oh, who knows what happen when you compile with `--std=c++0x`, `using namespace` both `std` and `boost` and a function named `bind`...

Comment: @Benoit: granted; this does not influence the above errors in any way though.

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this too. New and delete in my os are very expensive and I see it slowing the system on binding a member function. I can see no documentation about whether member functions are copied or not.

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_function_objects):

> By default, bind makes a copy of the provided function object. boost::ref and boost::cref can be used to make it store a reference to the function object, rather than a copy. This can be useful when the function object is noncopyable, expensive to copy, or contains state; of course, in this case the programmer is expected to ensure that the function object is not destroyed while it's still being used.

Comment: thx, but I did read the doc's before posting the Q (otherwise this would be an unfair use of StOv). Nonetheless, the docs were IMHO not too explicit about what happens. I now edited the question with effects of custom-defined cp cstr; it shows that boost::bind makes _three_ internal copies in this simple case; some info on how this process proceeds would be appreciated.